# RegExp: match with optional wrapping text

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the string `hello/pls/friend`. I might capture these words using the RegExp `/\w+/g`, resulting in `['hello', 'pls', 'friend']`.

Now consider the string `(hello)/pls/friend`. I'm now interested in not only the words, but also whether or not the each individual word is wrapped inside parentheses.

One solution I have come up with would be to 'duplicate' my original expression, adding a second version with (escaped) parentheses. Say...`/(\(\w+\))|(\w+)/g`

I'd rather not duplicate the original expression, so I'm wondering if there's a more succinct way to go about this.

The goals/requirements are:

1. This is being used with `String.prototype.replace()` with a callback specified, so keep that in mind if it's useful to you.
2. After some light manipulation, it should be possible to generate an object like so:

   ```
   [
     { word: "hello", wrapped: true },
     { word: "pls", wrapped: false },
     { word: "friend", wrapped: false } 
   ]
   ```
3. A mismatched parenthesis, i.e., `(hello/pls`, should not match.
4. These are JavaScript RegExps, so keep those limitations in mind
5. It does not need to handle multiple wrapped words, such as `(hello/pls)/friend`.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, RegExp pros!

Comment: Note: `/\(?\w+\)?/g` is almost equivalent, but does not satisfy condition 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\(([^/)]*)\)|[^/)(]*
```

You can use this.All the matches will come under `wrapped=False`.All the captured groups should come under `wrapped = True`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/85

Comment: It only took me a few years, but I was just going back through my questions and realized I never marked this one as answered. My past self thanks you for your help!

Comment: @jamesplease :)